# Rad a particular line from a string and then delete the rest in nodejs

Tags: node.js, regex

I have a string which is like

```
name : Rahul
surname : Chopra
school : KVMPSS
```

I need to read the first line , thats the `name : Rahul` then delete the rest. How can I do it. I am new to nodejs. Please help

Comment: What do you mean by "delete the rest"?  Is this string from a file or something, or is it a normal string?

Comment: @afghanimah Its from a  file

const check_String = fs.readFileSync("database.txt").toString();
Either i need to assign the first line to a variable. I think that will be more good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this to get the first line of your file:

```
your_string = "hi\nhello\nhello\nworld";
line_1 = your_string.split(/\r?\n/)[0];
console.log(line_1)
```

This is not efficient for large files, but it's fine for smaller ones.